# How to unit test Angular 2 RC4 component with Router

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular2-router

I am having an issue with unit testing angular 2 RC4 app with router. It gives me this error :

```
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known native property ("  <p>Please Go to <a href="/">Home</a></p>
```

I have implemented testing like this:

```
    beforeEach(() => {
    addProviders([
        FormBuilder,
        disableDeprecatedForms(),
        provideForms(),
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
       ROUTER_DIRECTIVES
    ])
});
```

Please help me through this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it By doing some workout, this may not be the perfect solution but as I have to do it any way I come with this one :

```
beforeEach(() => {
  addProviders([
    FormBuilder,
    disableDeprecatedForms(),
    provideForms(),
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
   {provide: PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES, multi: true, useValue: ROUTER_DIRECTIVES}
  ])
});
```